# Joining two search queries in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm not the best at SQL queries, I understand the basics and I wanted to do this query in a single one rather than two, I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `playerpdata` WHERE infoid LIKE '%Cash%' ORDER BY cast(value as int) DESC
```

It will return a result like to this:

```
infoid              value
3924839048[Cash]    60000
93849384[Cash]      43000
```

I then want to take the value before the [Cash] (which is the user id) and then preform this:

```
SELECT value FROM `playerpdata` WHERE infoid = '<ID FROM ABOVE>[CharacterName]'
```

I'd be really appreciative if someone could help me with this, thanks :)

edit;
Expected output:

```
infoid              value        value
3924839048[Cash]    60000        Joe Bloggs
93849384[Cash]      43000        Jane Doe
```

Comment: What are your expected results from combining the two queries?

Comment: I assume that redesigning the database structure is not an option, or is it?

Comment: Can you provide a `.dump` of a suitable toy db from SQLite command line tool? That would save everybody from typing a lot.

Comment: @AaronDietz Will update the OP now,
at Yunnosch Sadly no, as it's for a game which relies on the current structure, and give me one second to sort it out

Comment: In your first query you do `SELECT *` and there is no name field in the `playerpdata` table. Where do you expect it to come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple replace function should do the trick replacing cash with character name on the join.

```
SELECT PD.*, PD2.value
FROM `playerpdata`  PD
INNER JOIN `playerpdata` PD2
 on PD2.infoid = Replace(PD.InfoID,'[Cash]','[CharacterName]')
WHERE PD.infoid LIKE '%[Cash]' 
ORDER BY cast(PD.value as int) DESC
```

Though it makes more sense to have cash, charactername in a separate field. as a info type or something...

Note this assumes `[cash]` will not exist elsewhere in infoid.

or...  this approach generates PD and PD2 table aliases specific to cash or character name then joins on the ID w/o the [].  Just seems cleaner to me... but does assume the last part of infoID will always be in [] and define [charactername] or [cash]

```
SELECT PD.*, PD2.value
FROM `playerpdata`  PD
INNER JOIN `playerpdata` PD2
  on replace(PD2.infoid,'[CharacterName]','') = Replace(PD.InfoID,'[Cash]','')
 and PD.infoid LIKE '%[Cash]' 
 and PD2.InfoID like '%[CharacterName]')
ORDER BY cast(PD.value as int) DESC
```

Comment: It's interesting that we came up with answers independently and we both replaced his LIKE '%Cash%' with LIKE '%[Cash]' !

Comment: I like indexes.  @bloodless2010 needed to put `pd.value` on the order by.  only place a field existed w/o a table alias... which is needed since we're doing a self join so all columns will need an alais.

Comment: Tried running both queries and got the result 'ambiguous column name' , here is a SQL export if it's any help: https://hastebin.com/lerefezuva.sql edit: @xQbert, just ran the first one now and it returned some results but I got this: https://gyazo.com/1f1a82dda3c2078aff50511ffd1fc6d7

Comment: @xQbert changed the 'CASH' to Cash and everything worked fine, results are appearing correctly, https://gyazo.com/818b2a0648c614440feeff9c0b3a8083

Comment: I always get burned by case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `playerpdata` p1
LEFT OUTER JOIN `playerpdata` p2 ON p2.infoid = SUBSTR(1,LENGTH(p1.infoid)-6)||'[CharacterName]'
WHERE p1.infoid LIKE '%[Cash]' 
ORDER BY cast(p1.value as int) DESC
```